# Nginx Reverse Proxy is directing requests to a .255 address after several days

Tags: nginx, dns

I have nginx configured to perform two functions;

1 - To serve a set of html and javascript pages. The javascript pages iteratively access an API through the Nginx Proxy (see function 2).

2 - In order to get around CORS restrictions from the client/browser, nginx acts as a proxy to the remote api.

Everything works perfectly when nginx is first started and will run for several days to a couple of weeks. At some point, the client is no longer able to get data from two of the API endpoints. The ones that continue to work are retrieved using a GET. The ones that stop working use a POST method.

I looked in the nginx access.log and found:

192.168.100.7 - - [08/Dec/2020:23:01:24 +0000] "POST /example/developer_api/v1/companies/search HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://192.168.100.71/example-wdc/ExampleCompanies.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) tabprotosrv Safari/538.1"

A HTTP Error 499. Client closed request. This is 30 seconds after the previous successful GET request. I believe this is the originating client closing the connection before Nginx has received and returned data from the API.

I used wireshark on the nginx server to capture the traffic.

I found the following suspect packet:

104 6.716880257 192.168.100.71  XXX.XXX.XXX.**255** TCP 66  42920 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128

I think it is weird that the nginx proxy is sending a TCP SYN request to a broadcast address. The TCP SYN retried several times without any response. This explains the 499 from the originating client since Nginx hasn't had a response within 30 seconds.

I had a theory that the IP address had changed on the remove API server which then confused nginx on where to forward the requests.  I added a resolver with a timeout to nginx. This hasn't improved the situation.

So, I am stumped as to where to look next - any ideas, rabbit holes or weird theories will be appreciated.

I have included the nginx config below.

```
server {
        charset UTF-8;
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/tableau-web-data-connectors/webroot/;

        location /copper/ {
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '192.168.100.71';
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-C$
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
                resolver 192.168.100.10 valid=720s;
                proxy_pass https://api.example.com/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host api.prosperworks.com;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx uses "resolver" just once on start (or receiving HUP signal) for resolving api.example.com to ip-address (or any other domain names in configuration). Dynamic resolving works only for commercial Nginx+.

There is "POST /example/developer_api/v1/companies/search" with referer "http://192.168.100.71/example-wdc/ExampleCompanies.html".
Client opened "/example-wdc/ExampleCompanies.html" then clicked on the search form but didn't wait for result and closed the page. That's how 499 appeared in access_log. This is a common situation.

Perhaps it's just that nginx does not resolve api.example.com just when "api.example.com" changes its IP for some reason and stop working on old IP. Because resolving only works when nginx is restarted.
An IP ending in 255 is not always broadcast. This may be a valid address.